# WordPress Image Alt Tag is not showing up

Tags: wordpress, image, tags, alt

We're having a weird issue is that we can't see the ALT tags on few pages of our website. Below are the URLs of the pages.

Below is the homepage and ALT Tags are completely fine here.

- http://sensoft1.yourdevsite.ca/

And, this is the page, among a few others, where Image ALT Tags are not working.

- http://sensoft1.yourdevsite.ca/about-us/

We're testing these pages through Inspect Element Option (Developer Tool). Please, share your experiences to help us in this issue.

Comment: Did you check in the Media Library whether those images should have alt tags? I mean: is the alt tag set for those images? (Actually your logo does have an alt tag on the page where you say images do not have alt tags - this suggests that it's not the page's fault.)

Comment: Hi Muka, Images do have ALT tags in media library. It's just inspectors don't show it. Logo may be, because it's set under a different template(.PHP) file.

Comment: I checked your site (http://seositecheckup.com/seo-audit/image-alt-test/sensoft1.yourdevsite.ca/about-us), and 31 alt tags are missing - it's not only the inspector that does not show the alt tags. I would try to print (or echo or var_dump, var_exp, etc.) the image array - does it hold the key => value I'm after? Check whether a plugin plays a role in outputting the image codes (maybe the plugin's code is faulty), and look at differences in the correct and the not correct templates (or media placements in content).

Comment: Muka, it was a good hint. We tried putting image with the content itself. The ALT Tag works there. Now this confuses us even more that where is the problem actually. We doubt about our template file. We can't see the an echo for ALT and also the variable image is missing. I am commenting next a few lines of code. If that help!

Comment: <div class="circle">

<img src="<?=$image?>" alt="" />

</div>

<h4><?=$name?></h4>

<?php if($linkedin){?>

<a href="<?=$linkedin?>" class="linked_in icon_social" target="_blank">

<img src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/images/linked_icon.jpg" alt="" />

</a>

<?php } ?>

<div class="expand" id="coll<?=$count?>">

<div class="excert">    

<p><?php echo get_post_field('post_content', $people->ID);?></p>

 </div>

  <a href="#" class="more">More</a>

<a href="#" class="hide">Hide</a>    

</div>

Comment: Sry for the late reply. If the code above is the code in the template, then It think you are right - it looks as if nothing is in the 'alt=""' section. Try putting there something - anything (simple string) at first, and if it shows up in the inspector, then try to echo something with PHP (e.g. <?php echo $name; ?> - or something like that). If that also shows up, then you are only one step away from solving this question :) - just get the alt text from WP, and echo that.